# Open a pop up window with a push button QTcreator

Tags: c++, qt, software-design

i'm actually working on a project. Then, i want to open a pop up window with some other informations when i click on a push button which is on my main window. I work in c++ with QTcreator but i don't really know how to do that, and i didn't found on web a topic which could help me.

I have started to create an other class for my pop up's containt, and i've written the next method to open it but it doesn't work.

```
void MainWindow::button_is_pushed()
{
    pop_up_create_analyse* create_device_widget = new pop_up_create_analyse(this);
    create_device_widget->show();
}
```

Comment: Your code looks  to be correct. Guessing that `pop_up_create_analyse` is some type of `QWidget`. Maybe `button_is_pushed` was never triggered. You probably need to use your debugger to test. With that said you did not name it properly for automatic activation. For an automatic slot connection you need to name your slot in a specific format described by this Qt documentation: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName)

Comment: Thanks for your answer drescherjm !

Comment: Qt also provides helper classes for popup windows https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dialogs.html

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring  pop_up_create_analyse* outside of the method.

On your actual code, your pointer will be deleted immediately.

Didn't know what kind of widget is it, but you may also try changing the "show()" to "exec()". Exec() will actually wait for the window to be closed.